# cv::VideoWriter::open() failed

Tags: c++, opencv

Source code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/videoio.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/utils/logger.hpp>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cv::utils::logging::setLogLevel(cv::utils::logging::LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE);
    cv::VideoWriter writer;
    if (!writer.open("hello.mp4", cv::VideoWriter::fourcc('M', 'P', '4', 'V'), 25, cv::Size(100, 100))) {
        std::cerr << argv[0] << ": cannot open" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
[DEBUG:0@0.001] global /builddir/build/BUILD/opencv-4.5.5/modules/videoio/src/videoio_registry.cpp (197) VideoBackendRegistry VIDEOIO: Builtin backends(8): FFMPEG(1000); GSTREAMER(990); INTEL_MFX(980); V4L2(970); CV_IMAGES(960); CV_MJPEG(950); FIREWIRE(940); UEYE(930)
[DEBUG:0@0.001] global /builddir/build/BUILD/opencv-4.5.5/modules/videoio/src/videoio_registry.cpp (221) VideoBackendRegistry VIDEOIO: Available backends(8): FFMPEG(1000); GSTREAMER(990); INTEL_MFX(980); V4L2(970); CV_IMAGES(960); CV_MJPEG(950); FIREWIRE(940); UEYE(930)
[ INFO:0@0.001] global /builddir/build/BUILD/opencv-4.5.5/modules/videoio/src/videoio_registry.cpp (223) VideoBackendRegistry VIDEOIO: Enabled backends(8, sorted by priority): FFMPEG(1000); GSTREAMER(990); INTEL_MFX(980); V4L2(970); CV_IMAGES(960); CV_MJPEG(950); FIREWIRE(940); UEYE(930)
[ INFO:0@0.001] global /builddir/build/BUILD/opencv-4.5.5/modules/videoio/src/backend_plugin.cpp (369) getPluginCandidates VideoIO plugin (FFMPEG): glob is 'libopencv_videoio_ffmpeg*.so', 1 location(s)
[ INFO:0@0.008] global /builddir/build/BUILD/opencv-4.5.5/modules/videoio/src/backend_plugin.cpp (379) getPluginCandidates     - /lib64: 0
[ INFO:0@0.008] global /builddir/build/BUILD/opencv-4.5.5/modules/videoio/src/backend_plugin.cpp (383) getPluginCandidates Found 0 plugin(s) for FFMPEG
[ WARN:0@0.016] global /builddir/build/BUILD/opencv-4.5.5/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (2180) open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: cannot link elements
MFX: Can't initialize session
[ INFO:0@0.016] global /builddir/build/BUILD/opencv-4.5.5/modules/videoio/src/cap_images.cpp (282) icvExtractPattern Pattern: hello.mp%01d @ 4
./a.out: cannot open
```

Fedora Linux.
opencv-4.5.5-5.fc36.src.rpm

Is this the wrong library in the fedora repositories?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this specific issue. But some codecs have problems with "non-standard" frame sizes. You can try (640,480). You can also try other `fourcc`s (at least in order to narrow the possible problem cause).

Comment: Can you try a resolution that is divisible by 32 in each dimension?

Comment: FOURCC is case sensitive. Try replacing `fourcc('M', 'P', '4', 'V')` with `fourcc('m', 'p', '4', 'v')`.

Comment: `writer.open("hello.mp4", cv::VideoWriter::fourcc('m', 'p', '4', 'v'), 25, cv::Size(640, 480))` same problem